# How to change Nlog.config variable value using powershell script

Tags: powershell, nlog.config

I am trying to change variable value ="1" for name ="one" for different environment using PowerShell
script for azure
devops .I am not able do it for nlog.config and getting **'D:\pss\nlog.config' does not have the 'one' key inside the file node** Not sure what I am doing wrong ?.  Nlog.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog
xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
autoReload="true" 
throwExceptions="false" 
internalLogLevel="Trace"
internalLogFile="d:\log.txt">
<variable name="one" value="1" />
<variable name="two" value="2" />

<targets async="true">
  <target name="default"
  xsi:type="File"
  fileName="${Directory}\NLog_${date:format=yyyyMMddHH}.log"
  layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message}}|${exception:format=ToString,StackTrace}" keepFileOpen="false" />
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" writeTo="default" minlevel="Debug" />
  <logger name="*" writeTo="eventlog" minlevel="Error" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

**Powershell Script :**

```
   $configPath = 'D:\pss\nlog.config'
   $key = "one"
   $value = "11"
       $XPath = "nlog/variable[@name='$key']"
       $Attribute = "value"
       $xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $configPath)
       $xmlNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode($XPath)
       if ($xmlNode) 
       {
           $xmlNode.SetAttribute($Attribute, $value)
           $xml.Save($configPath)   
          Write-Host ("Config customHeaders has been Update "+$configPath+" on key: "+$key+" with the value " + $value)
       }
       else
       {
          Write-Host ("Config '"+$configPath+"' does not have the '"+ $key + "' key inside the file node.")
       }
```

Any help or advice would be great . Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the value of nlog in app.config file using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139973/how-to-change-the-value-of-nlog-in-app-config-file-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$configPath = 'D:\pss\nlog.config'
$key = "one"
$value = "11"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $configPath)
```

```
$xml.nlog.variable.Where{ $_.Name -eq $key }.Foreach{ $_.value = $value }
```

```
$xml.Save($configPath)
```

Comment: Thanks IRon.  How do we get the status of $xml.nlog.variable.Where{ $_.Name -eq $key }.Foreach{ $_.value = $value } . if it's a success  or failure ?

Comment: There is no status, meaning `$xml.nlog.variable.Where{ $_.Name -eq $key }` either truthifies by returning one (*or more*) nodes or falsifies by returning an [`System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.1#empty-null). In other words, you might do something like: `$xmlNode = $xml.nlog.variable.Where{ $_.Name -eq $key }; if ($xmlNode.count -eq 1)  { $xmlNode.Foreach{ $_.value = $value } } else { ...`